Salesforce record sharing
There are sets of records owned by user A, and user A is going on a vacation for 10 days
I want to share those records with user B for 10 day's
After the return of user A, user B should lose the access to those records
How can we achieve this in salesforce

welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. In your case, what options have you looked at? (use [edit])

You can't arbitrarily schedule sharing directly. That said, many people have built custom sharing solutions. For example, you could create a custom object that keeps track of when shares should start and end, and then use a Scheduled Flow, Record-Triggered Scheduled Paths, Scheduled Apex, etc to enact the changes to sharing.
